# Family link setup; one child, two parents

Tags: google-family-link

Me and the mother of my daughter have separated. My daughter is with me on odd weeks and her mother on even weeks. I have set up Family link to work on my phone and my daughter's. We would like to be able to switch control of my daughters phone via Family link between me and her mother.

I have searched but not found an answer to if that is possible and how you do it. Can you help me?